# using --environments with Angular SPA on Asp.net core 2 Visual Studio 2017

Tags: angular, visual-studio

I am running the Visual Studio 2017 Angular SPA template and I want to add in the use of angular environment variables to work in production and development.

I am running the following version of angular in my `package.json` file;

```
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.8",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.7",
```

I have created the `/environments` folder in my `ClientApp/app` foldere and added my `environment.prod.ts` and `environment.ts` files.

An example is;

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    appUrl: 'http://localhost:61996',
    apiUrl: 'http://localhost:61996'
};
```

How do I then go about configuring this to work with my SPA? As the current template doesn't contain a `.angular-cli.json` file I see referenced on tutorial websites?

My aim is to be able to run in debug using 'environment.prod.ts`and then web deploy the`environment.ts` with my publish.

Answer (score 1):

In your `angular.json` you have an configuration section where you can define a fileReplacement.

```
"build": {
    "configurations": {
         "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [ {
                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                    "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }]
           },
           "prod": {
              "fileReplacements": [ {
                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }]
           }
     }
}
```

To use the *dev environment* you have to add `--configuration=dev`

Comment: where do you add that flag?

Comment: Yes, where do you add --configuration=dev?

Comment: `ng build --configuration=dev`

Comment: @take Since this is a C# SPA I do not think we have access to the commands directly. They seem to be tucked away in the csproj file. Furthermore if we have multiple 'publishing profiles' it seems to be fairly difficult to have those profiles run seperate commands. Have you had any experience configuring something of this nature? (Multiple Profiles one dev one prod and having the ng build command dynamically output the --configuration switch?)